# $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|_{\mathbb{Q}})$ is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Hello i have this exercise:

let $(E,d)$ a connected metric space, with an unbounded metric, show that the sphere is not empty, after deduce that $(\mathbb{Q},|.|_{\mathbb{Q}})$ is not connected.

I prove the first question, but I have I problem with the second one, from the first question we deduce that if the sphere is empty then the space is not connected or the distance is bounded, but $|.|_{\mathbb{Q}} $ is the discrete distance so it is bounded, then how to deduce that  $(\mathbb{Q},|.|_{\mathbb{Q}})$ is not connected?

Thank you

Comment: Write down a nontrivial set $A\subset\Bbb Q$ which is both open and closed.

Comment: Are you certain that $|\cdot|_{\Bbb Q}$ is the discrete distance?

Comment: I think the intersection of intervals with Q is only the elements of Q, what it can be?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I have to use the first question

Comment: What is "the" sphere? Surely $S(x,1/2)$ is empty for the usual metric on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @freakish the discreat topology is.bounded right

Comment: @PolineSandra Not the discrete, my bad. Natural metric on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand what is the relation with N ?

Comment: @freakish But $\Bbb N$ is not connected.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah, fair enough, missed the assumption.

Comment: Any non-compact metrizable space has an unbounded metric. In the case of an infinite discrete space $X$ this is easy: Partition $X$ as $X=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}X_n$ where each $X_n$ is non-empty and where $X_m\cap X_n$ is empty when $m\ne n$.  Let $d(x,y)=1 $ if  $x$ and $y$ belong to the same  $X_n$. If $x\in X_m$ and $ y\in X_n$ with $m\ne n$, let $d(x,y)=|m-n|$.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $|\cdot|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ **is not** a discrete metric. It is not a metric at all since it only takes 1 argument!

It is most likely a norm, probably the Euclidean one that induces a metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Assuming that $|x|_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the standard Euclidean norm, i.e. the absolute value then the induced metric is not bounded, since $d(n,0)=n$ for natural $n$.

And to conclude that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected it is enough to consider the sphere centered at $0$ with radius $\sqrt{2}$.